# solr stopwords not working

Tags: solr, stop-words

Need help..

Solr Stopwords doesn't work for the common words like "the" "in" "an" but it works for other uncommon words like "diesel" etc.

I can see that the stopwords are getting listed in the solr server . however, solr search doesn't stop them .

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "wordSet":{
    "initArgs":{"ignoreCase":"true"},
    "initializedOn":"2016-06-16T12:13:20.69Z",
    "managedList":["in",
      "the"]}}
```

Here is my schema.xml . Can anyone please tell me what could be the issue.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="en" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: did you analyased the same in solr analysis page?

Answer (score 0):

You have two different Stop filter factories. Just keep one to get things better.

Then, use Admin UI's Analysis screen to see what happens with a phrase as it goes through the analyzer stack. That should show you whether the work is kept or dropped.

Finally, you need to double check whether the field you are searching against **is** the one you think you are searching against (and not - for example - a catch-all field with different analyzer). Enabling debug should show that to you.